# How to split shape in Scribus?

Tags: scribus

I would like to have a simple split like this in Scribus. Is there any way to do that? Note that the real shape I need to cut is more complicate than that.
[image]

Comment: I get the answer in [Scribus forum](http://forums.scribus.net/index.php/topic,1533.msg6757.html#msg6757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of others, and possibly in addition to the answers provided in the linked Scribus forum post, Scribus has a set of boolean tools you can use on paths.

The Scribus forum answer suggests using  `Item -> Path Tools -> Cut Polygon` having first selected a polygon and a bezier curve to cut it. (It doesn't work for me if the intended cut line is merely a "line")

If you're more minded to deal with combinations of volumes then select two polygon items and then in the menu go `Item -> Path Tools -> Path Operations...`

I think the dialogue is pretty self explanatory:[image: Scribus Boolean Path Operations dialogue]

As the operations are so deep in the menu structure and not available in a right-click menu I cursed Scribus for a while for its apparent lack of functionality until I discovered these.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried your method yet, but if you can confirm that, I will accept yours.

Comment: I wish they have a ribbon menu instead.